# Convert local coordinate system to global system and vice versa

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to convert local coordinate system to global coordinate system and vise versa.
I have 3 position coordinates and 3 rotating angles, so my input is `(X, Y, Z, RX, RY, RZ)`.

I'm trying to understand the theory of this process, but I don't have enough experience in math science to extract information from math docs efficiently (I just don't understand them, but I'm trying).

So, can someone explain the coordinate system converting process in simple terms? I just feel a lack of examples.

I already read about rotating and shifting matrixes, but I can't understand how to use them to obtain new `X, Y, Z` and their `rotating angles` at the end... Just mess in my head.

In addition I'll be really thanks for the tips on researching this issue.

**UPD**: Here is the illustration of the problem with example.
[image]
We have two coordinate systems. `A - world system`, `A' - local system`.
Both systems has the same scale, but for example `A' system` has cutted axis, just to improve readability.

Magenta ball is an object, located in `system A'`.
His coordinates and rotation angles (let shorten it up to CRa) in this system are: `(1.2, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0)`.
`System A'` is located in `system A`. `System A'` CRa in `system A` are: `(0, 3, 5, 90, 0, 0)`.

So,
I have ball's CRa in `system A'`.
I have `system A'` CRa in `system A`.

*I need to find ball's CRa in `system A`.*

(and vise versa, I need to find ball's CRa in `system A'` in case I have `system A'` CRa in `system A` and ball's CRa in `system A`.)

Comment: If you only had (X, Y, Z) and not (X, Y, Z, RX, RY, RZ), all you'd need would be to write the matrix A called the "change of basis matrix" which is a matrix simply made by writing the coordinates of the basis vectors of one base in the other base, one column per vector, and then you could do `newvector = A @ oldvector` where `@` is matrix-vector multiplication. However you have to be very careful and basically have 50% chance of getting it wrong if you don't know the math (is it newvector = A @ oldvector or oldvector = A @ newvector?)

Comment: But since you have RX, RY and RZ in addition... I need a cup of coffee before I can think about a simple way to apply the change of basis matrix to these rotation angles.

Comment: PS: I upvoted your question, which I think is a great question that probably lots of people have been facing when implementing 3d geometry. However your question has already received a closevote. I don't know why. StackOverflow can be unwelcoming like that sometimes.

Comment: Actually, you probably need to tell us more about your three angles. Could you put a small drawing of a 3d vector with the x,y,z axis and showing the angles rx, ry, rz in that drawing?

Comment: @Stef, thank you for yor answers. I've attached an example with diagram

Answer (score 1):

The process of transforming between coordinates can be viewed as a two step process.

Just imagine you have these [image]

To transform any points, or vector, from the UV system to XY system, what do you do? You would first ROTATE by some amount, to make UV match the orientation of XY, then you would TRANSLATE UV back the where XY is, right? So for example I have some point, (6,4) in the XY system. the actual representation in XY system is P = O + 6X + 4Y, which effectively, is saying you have where XY are your unit vector along the axis. Why? Because you are moving 6 in your X direction, and 4 in your Y direction, plus the distance from the origin O.

You can represent this in a matrix form: [[1,0],[0,1]] @ [6,4] + O.

Same idea applies. To represent the point in new UV, you would go about P' = I + aU + bV. where (a,b) is your new coordinates.

So effectively, you are figuring out a matrix, [[ux, uy],[vx,vy]], that when multiplied by your [a,b], gives back [6,4]. Or some matrix when multiplied by [6,4], gives you back [a,b].

In order to find this matrix, you look at the relationship between UV and XY. Does it look like that you actually rotated it by some amount, and the moved it by some amount? So that is where the (X, Y, Z, RX, RY, RZ) comes in. These represents the amount you translate (x,y,z) and rotate (RX,RY,RZ). The rest goes about how you put these in a single matrix where you can google on homogenous transformation.

Comment: Anna, thank you for such detailed answer. I's still kinda complicated for me, but I'm trying to understand and keep searching. :))